# How to fire an event on ListView row click?

Tags: c#, wpf

I've a `ListView` with a basic structure:

```
<ListView Name="Playing" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedItems}}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Date" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path = MatchDate}"/>
             <GridViewColumn Header="Minute" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path = MatchMinute}"/>
         </GridView>
     </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I populate this list from an `ObservableCollection`. In this list are displayed a list of events. Now each event have an id, that I've saved as link. The link is the page associated with this event.

What I need to do is display a new window that contain the details of this event, the window should be opened from an event that is fired when the user click on the specific row.

Now the main problem is: How can I assign an event with the `link` (id) of each row programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to set the `ItemContainerStyle` property of `ListView` in which you will provide an `EventSetter` for the `ListViewItem` `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` Event.

```
        <ListView>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
               ......
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown"
                             Handler="ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>
```

Then in its handler you can open a new window based on the info you get from its DataContext:

```
 private void ListViewItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = sender as ListViewItem;
        var context = item.DataContext as yourdatatype;

        //open your new window 

    }
```

Comment: this even return `null`  in the `item` variable

Comment: just a problem: `'Models.Event' is a 'type', that is not a valid construct in the specified context` where `Models.Event` is the class that I type in `yourdataObject`

Comment: @AgainMe dont include the brackets.